# How to load non-default PaddleOCR detection model in a python script?

Tags: python, ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr, east-text-detector

PaddleOCR seems to support different algorithms/models for text detection, as written in their [algorithms overview](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.6/doc/doc_en/algorithm_overview_en.md). However, when trying to load a different model from "DB" (for example "SAST" or "EAST") an error is encountered (I get the following error: `ppocr ERROR: det_algorithm must in ['DB']`). From the code it seems that only the "DB" model is supported - see [here](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/013870d9bc963f7508d5a76f81da872b84471a71/paddleocr.py#L49). I have downloaded the models from the [links](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/013870d9bc963f7508d5a76f81da872b84471a71/paddleocr.py#L49) posted in the documentation, is there a way to use them in a python script? I don't intend to use them as illustrated in the [tutorial](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.6/doc/doc_en/algorithm_det_east_en.md), for example running `python3 tools/infer/predict_det.py --image_dir="./doc/imgs_en/img_10.jpg" --det_model_dir="./inference/det_r50_east/" --det_algorithm="EAST"`.

I have tried something like the following:

```
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR

ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang="en", det_algorithm="DB")
result = ocr.ocr(img, cls=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have installed the paddleOCR using the whl package. The whl package currently only supports the DB algorithm. For predictions of other models, it is recommended to clone the entire project. You can view this discussion [here](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/issues/3220#issuecomment-871128969)